# d3 sort only applies to select rows

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, html-table

I am trying to use the sort function to sort rows in a table in ascending order.

```
var forsort = d3.keys(csv[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key != "name";
});

var tr = d3.selectAll("tbody tr");      
d3.selectAll("thead th").data(forsort).on("click", function(k) {
    tr.sort(d3.ascending);
});
```

For some reason only 3 rows out of 18 are being swapped (rows 2,3,11 to be precise) with row 2 being the first sortable row.

Can someone tell me what the problem can be?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle (or at least post your data and all code) to make it easier to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: this is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/rkr2/Ba8D8/

`data: 
name,bh,md,sp,bm
AL,152,10,7,0
AO,82,9,8.5,-1
AP,481,11,7.5,0.8387097
BE,14,-1,8.8,0.5806451
DI,14,13,7.7,0.4285714
EC,801,-1,7.7,0.9032258
ED,-1,-1,8.2,0.5517241
EF,-1,9,8.8,0
EM,723,7,7.2,-1
JF,-1,4,9.5,0
KGS,111,15,6.6,0
KS,-1,15,8.8,0
MM,-1,8,7.2,0
MO,439,12,8,0.6774194
PC,27,-1,8.4,-1
PO,0,12,8.8,0.5806451
TL,2312,6,9.2,-1
VM,-1,9,6.6,0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the d3 documentation, `d3.ascending` looks like this

```
function(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

What are `a` and `b` in your case? You can check by, instead, sorting like this:

`tr.sort(function(a,b){ console.log('compare', a, b); });`

I'm guessing that `a` and `b` are objects, in which case sorting them with greater/less -than would be meaningless.

**Edit:**

To sort by the key of the column that was clicked, you need to use the `k` attribute you're getting from the click handler (I have no way of verifying this, but I'm pretty sure that's what `k` is – a string corresponding to the column/attribute name).

So, ditch the use of d3.ascending and do the sorting like this:

```
tr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[k] < b[k] ? -1 : a[k] > b[k] ? 1 : 0;
})
```

Alternatively, you can still use d3.ascending like this:

```
tr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a[k], b[k]);
})
```

It's not much of a difference in principle. But, one benefit of the latter is that it makes it easier to implement something that'll give users control over sort direction (ascending vs descending). Something like this:

```
var sortFunction = d3.ascending;
// Instead of the line above, you could write some logic
// to decide whether sortFunction is d3.ascending or d3.descending

// Then you can write:
tr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sortFunction(a[k], b[k]);
})
```

Comment: It is as you said Amit, a and b and objects of the rows, with key value pairs of the column name and value.
Can I pass the value based on the column that was clicked? (i.e. sort by column)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

It's working but the sorting is done in no way I can understand. Some smaller values show up after larger ones. Also, click the same column multiple times leads to a sort of rearranging of some subset of rows. (rather than staying sorted as it is after the first click).

Any idea what can cause such behavior?